Migrating code from MSGraph V5.6 to MSGraph V6 in java
I got multiple methods i developed in graph v5.6
But now i need to update them to v6.x i am stuck with these 2 methods
One to update metdada data of a file i found by query
    protected static synchronized FieldValueSet postTagsToFile(GraphServiceClient graphClient, String driveId, String fileId, Map<String, String> metadata){
        metadata.forEach((s, s2) -> {
            if (!s2.isEmpty())
                System.out.println(s + " : " + s2);
        });
        FieldValueSet fieldValueSet = new FieldValueSet();
        metadata.forEach((key, value) -> fieldValueSet.additionalDataManager().put(key, new JsonPrimitive(value)));
        return graphClient.drives(driveId).items(fileId).listItem().fields().buildRequest().patch(fieldValueSet);
    }

Problem is that in the graph v6.x examples i need to have the list Id to update this, and i dont know how to have access to the listId in this method.
And one to upload a file to a location
    public static String uploadFileToSharedSP(String fileName,String mimeType, String fileContent, String location) throws IOException {
    
        DriveItem newItem = new DriveItem();
        newItem.name = fileName;
        newItem.file = new com.microsoft.graph.models.File();
        newItem.file.mimeType = mimeType;
    
        DriveRequestBuilder driverReq = graphClient.sites(SHARED_SITE_ID).drive();
        DriveItemRequestBuilder driverRootReq = driverReq.root();
        DriveItemRequestBuilder destination = driverRootReq.itemWithPath(location);
    
        DriveItem createdDriveItem = destination.children().buildRequest().post(newItem);
    
        driverReq.items(createdDriveItem.id)
                .content()
                .buildRequest()
                .put(fileContent.getBytes());
    
        return createdDriveItem.webUrl+"?web=1";
    }

in this i dont know how to post the new file with the content to the location in the new api
There is no example i can find that i can follow.
I have been searching all online but i dont seem to be able to find a way to do this.

i was able to update the first one like this
    public static synchronized FieldValueSet postTagsToFile(GraphServiceClient graphClient, String driveId, String fileId, Map<String, String> metadata){

        ListItemRequestBuilder listItemReq = graphClient.drives().byDriveId(driveId).items().byDriveItemId(fileId).listItem();
        ListItem listItem = listItemReq.get();

        metadata.forEach((s, s2) -> {
            if (!s2.isEmpty())
                System.out.println(s + " : " + s2);
        });
        FieldValueSet fieldValueSet = new FieldValueSet();
        fieldValueSet.setAdditionalData(Collections.unmodifiableMap(metadata));

        SharepointIds sharepointIds = listItem.getSharepointIds();

        FieldValueSet result = graphClient.sites()
                .bySiteId(sharepointIds.getSiteId())
                .lists().byListId(sharepointIds.getListId())
                .items().byListItemId(listItem.getId())
                .fields().patch(fieldValueSet);

        return result;
}

My error was that i did not know that there is a new Propertie in the list item, that i could use to get the listId that the item belongs to, and with that i can post and update the fields.
and the second one my mistake was not adding a : at the end of the path
public static String uploadFileToSharedSP(String fileName,String mimeType, String fileContent, String location) throws Exception {


    Drive drive = graphClient.sites().bySiteId(SHARED_SITE_ID).drive().get();

    String destination = location+"/"+fileName;

    DriveItemUploadableProperties properties = new DriveItemUploadableProperties();
    properties.getAdditionalData().put("@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "replace");

    CreateUploadSessionPostRequestBody uploadSessionRequest = new CreateUploadSessionPostRequestBody();
    uploadSessionRequest.setItem(properties);

    UploadSession uploadSession = graphClient.drives()
            .byDriveId(drive.getId())
            .items()
            .byDriveItemId("root:/"+destination+":")
            .createUploadSession()
            .post(uploadSessionRequest);

    int maxSliceSize = 1_000_000;
    InputStream uploadStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent.getBytes());
    long streamSize = fileContent.getBytes().length;


    LargeFileUploadTask<DriveItem> largeFileUploadTask = new LargeFileUploadTask<>(
            graphClient.getRequestAdapter(),
            uploadSession,
            uploadStream,
            streamSize,
            maxSliceSize,
            DriveItem::createFromDiscriminatorValue);

    IProgressCallback callback = (current, max) -> logger.info("Uploaded {} bytes of {} total bytes", current, max);
    UploadResult<DriveItem> uploadResult = largeFileUploadTask.upload(5, callback);
    if (uploadResult.isUploadSuccessful()) {
        String itemId = uploadResult.itemResponse.getId();
        String webUrl = uploadResult.itemResponse.getWebUrl();
        logger.info("Upload successful. itemId: {}, webUrl: {}", itemId, webUrl);
        return webUrl+"?web=1";
    } else {
        logger.error("For Upload failed to {}", destination);
        throw new IOException("To: "+destination+", Upload failed");
    }

}

